# how is it that a corrected pairwise comparison yields a p.value < then a single t.test?

Tags: r, statistics, t-test, pairwise

Hi suppose I have these results

```
df <- structure(list(len = c(4.2, 11.5, 7.3, 5.8, 6.4, 10, 11.2, 11.2, 
5.2, 7, 15.2, 21.5, 17.6, 9.7, 14.5, 10, 8.2, 9.4, 16.5, 9.7, 
16.5, 16.5, 15.2, 17.3, 22.5, 17.3, 13.6, 14.5, 18.8, 15.5, 19.7, 
23.3, 23.6, 26.4, 20, 25.2, 25.8, 21.2, 14.5, 27.3, 23.6, 18.5, 
33.9, 25.5, 26.4, 32.5, 26.7, 21.5, 23.3, 29.5, 25.5, 26.4, 22.4, 
24.5, 24.8, 30.9, 26.4, 27.3, 29.4, 23), supp = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("OJ", 
"VC"), class = "factor"), dose = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("D0.5", "D1", "D2"
), class = "factor")), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 
40L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 41L, 42L, 
43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 
26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 
59L, 60L), class = "data.frame") 

df$int <- interaction(df$supp, df$dose)
e <- pairwise.t.test(df$len, df$int, p.adjust.method="BH")
```

so from the output

```
        OJ.D0.5          VC.D0.5            OJ.D1     VC.D1            OJ.D2  
VC.D0.5 0.00285          -                  -         -                -      
OJ.D1   0.00000079391014 0.00000000000984   -         -                -      
VC.D1   0.04207          0.00000243821908 **0.00088** -                -      
OJ.D2   0.00000000042891 0.00000000000001   0.04645   0.00000089414918 -      
VC.D2   0.00000000042891 0.00000000000001   0.04474   0.00000085310153 0.96089
```

the comparison of, **VC.D1 vs OJ.D1 = 0.00088**

however a single t.test

```
t.test(df[df$supp == "VC" & df$dose == "D1", ]$len, 
       df[df$supp == "OJ" & df$dose == "D1", ]$len)
```

yields a p.value = p-value = 0.001038

so I most have messed up somewhere because shouldn't an adjusted p value be greater than a single uncorrected p value?

Comment: Should you put `paired=TRUE" in the second block?

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

You'll get the same results when you set `p.adjust.method = "none"` and `pool.sd = FALSE`:

```r
pairwise.t.test(df$len, df$int, p.adjust.method = "none", pool.sd = FALSE)$p.value[3,3]
# 0.001038376

t.test(df[df$supp == "VC" & df$dose == "D1", ]$len, 
       df[df$supp == "OJ" & df$dose == "D1", ]$len)$p.value
# 0.001038376
```

**Notes**

1. Just a reminder to always carefully read documentation and perform some sanity checks, to make sure the function does what you think it does.
2. This only illustrates where the difference comes from. How to run it in your case will have to depend on your familiarity with the data.

**Explanation**

The comparison becomes much easier when we simply don't apply multiple testing correction. In that case, they should have the same p-value, right? So let's compare using `p.adjust.method = "none"`. When running `pairwise.t.test` we now get `0.00059`... closer, but still not right.

The problem stems from the `pool.sd` argument. This forces the use of a common standard deviation across *all* comparisons. This is useful in general (if the assumption is met), but does lead to different p-values.

When we look at the underlying code, this becomes clear:

```r
if (pool.sd) {
        METHOD <- "t tests with pooled SD"
        xbar <- tapply(x, g, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
        s <- tapply(x, g, sd, na.rm = TRUE)
        n <- tapply(!is.na(x), g, sum)
        degf <- n - 1
        total.degf <- sum(degf)
        pooled.sd <- sqrt(sum(s^2 * degf)/total.degf)
        compare.levels <- function(i, j) {
            dif <- xbar[i] - xbar[j]
            se.dif <- pooled.sd * sqrt(1/n[i] + 1/n[j])
            t.val <- dif/se.dif
            if (alternative == "two.sided") 
                2 * pt(-abs(t.val), total.degf)
            else pt(t.val, total.degf, lower.tail = (alternative == 
                "less"))
        }
    }
```

Amongst others, a total degrees of freedom is calculated across the tests (`total.degf`) which is then used to calculate a pooled standard deviation (`pooled.sd`).

when we set `pool.sd = FALSE`, the code simply uses the `t.test` function:

```r
    else {
        METHOD <- if (paired) 
            "paired t tests"
        else "t tests with non-pooled SD"
        compare.levels <- function(i, j) {
            xi <- x[as.integer(g) == i]
            xj <- x[as.integer(g) == j]
            t.test(xi, xj, paired = paired, alternative = alternative, 
                ...)$p.value
        }
    }
```